# git log summary

Tags: git, logging

I am new to git and I am trying to accomplish the following: I want to print a short summary listing commits title, author, timestamp(optional), and just number of addition/deletion/update.

What I have done is I use `git log --shortstat --oneline` and it *almost* achieves my requirements except it lacks the author that committed the changes. Can I tweak the command abit to show the author as well?

P/S: This is what I get from the command above and I want it to show the authors as well.

```
2d2b0b9 Commit#1 **[Authors]**    
 2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
e90dc73 Commit#2 **[Authors]**    
 2 files changed, 20 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at `git log --pretty=format:<format string>`, [Here is a good explanation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).

For exmaple

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ae): %s" --shortstat
```

will give you the hash (`%h`), the author name and email (`%an`, `%ae`) and the subject (`%s`), followed by the `--shortstat` line

Comment: That precisely answers my question and the link you gave me? Its really really good. Thanks alot.